# How to Remove year(yyyy) in date(dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: java, android-studio, date, datetime

I have below dates,

```
24/04/2019

13/05/2019

12/04/2019
```

I want to remove the year and convert these dates into following format,

```
24/04

13/05

12/04
```

This not for output only I want to perform addition or apply for loop on that date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the substring from index 0 to 4:

```
String input = "24/04/2019";
String output = input.substring(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

```
MonthDay                     // Represent a month & day-of-month, without a year.
.from(                       // Extract a `MonthDay` from a `LocalDate`, omitting the year but keeping the month and day-of-month.
    LocalDate                // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    .parse(                  // Parse a string to get a `LocalDate`.
        "24/04/2019" ,       // FYI, better to use standard ISO 8601 formats rather than devising a custom format such as this.
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" )  // Match the formatting pattern of your input strings.
    )                        // Returns a `LocalDate`. 
)                            // Returns a `MonthDay`.
.format(                     // Generate a `String` with text representing the value of this `MonthDay` object.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM" ) 
)                            // Returns a `String`.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/evCOhN).

> 24/04

## `LocalDate` & `MonthDay`

Java comes built-in with classes for this work:

- [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)
  Represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).
- [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html)
  Represents a day in a month, generically speaking, without a year.

Parse your input strings to get `LocalDate` objects. Define a formatting pattern to match the input format.

```
String input = "24/04/2019" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
```

Parse.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, YYYY-MM-DD. I strongly encourage you to use these formats when exchanging date-time values as text, rather than devising your own custom formats.

The *java.time* classes uses these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

> 2019-04-24

Extract just the month and day, while leaving out the year.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.from( ld ) ;  // Extract the month & day-of-month, but omit the year.
```

[Generate a string](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html#toString()) in standard ISO 8601 format. The format uses double hyphens in front to indicate the missing year.

```
String output = md.toString():
```

> --04-24

You can parse this value as well.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse( "--04-24" ) ;
```

You can get back to a `LocalDate` by specifying a year.

```
LocalDate ld = md.atYear( 2019 ) ;  // Generate a `LocalDate` by specifying a year to go with the month & day.
```

> not for output only I want to perform addition or apply for loop on that date.

Study the JavaDoc for both classes. Many handy methods are offered.

You can compare with `isBefore` and `isAfter`.

You can do math, adding or subtracting spans-of-time. You can adjust, such as jumping to a specific day-of-month. Note that the *java.time* classes follow the [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern. So rather than changing (“mutating”) the original, a second object is created with values based on the original.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
String input = "24/04/2019";
String output = input.substring(0,input.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try with string split logic as below.

```
String date="24/04/2019";

String [ ] ddyymm=date.split("/");

 String output=ddyymm[0]+"/"+ddmmyy[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following code to cover all cases where the year may come at the begginning

```
var dateFormat = deviceDateFormat.replace("(?i)y".toRegex(), "")
if (!dateFormat.first().isLetter()) dateFormat = dateFormat.drop(1)
if (!dateFormat[dateFormat.length - 1].isLetter()) dateFormat = dateFormat.dropLast(1)
println(dateFormat)
```